# Return OUTPUT from inserted + inner join and return values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm soft-locking records this way:

```
UPDATE TOP (10) TABLEA SET STATUS = 5 
                         OUTPUT inserted.*
                         FROM TABLEA A
                         INNER JOIN TABLEB B 
                         ON A.EMAIL = B.VALUE
```

Now, would it be possible to return values of the joined table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Status INT)

UPDATE A 
SET STATUS = 5 
OUTPUT inserted.STATUS   INTO  @T(Status)
FROM TABLEA A INNER JOIN TABLEB B 
ON A.EMAIL = B.VALUE 

SELECT * FROM @T
```

Comment: Also possible to use the following: UPDATE TOP (10) TABLEA SET STATUS = 5 
                         OUTPUT inserted.*, B.blabla
                         FROM TABLEA A
                         INNER JOIN TABLEB B 
                         ON A.EMAIL = B.VALUE